# DPI-independent constant size in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have a visual component in my app written in QML, Qt5. I want it to always have the width of **`5 cm`** on the screen, no matter what device is used.

If I set `width: somevalue`, then the DPI might differ among the devices which will result in different physical size on different devices.

Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've just might've found a solution: `Screen.pixelDensity`. But feel free to suggest anything better.